# How to Implement tab navigation swipe using Mobile angular UI like whts app tabs

Tags: angularjs, css, mobile-angular-ui

I want to implement a swipable tab based on the Mobile-Angular-UI. What I want to accomplish is to be able to swipe on the tabs, if the user wants to change to another one. So if a user swiped where it says "Tab #2" they would be able to move to TAB3 without having to actually click TAB3.

[image]

Plnkr : `

> `'http://plnkr.co/edit/c4EXHa0C8jjPIRT6e6sN?p=preview'`

`

Comment: could you add plunkr/fiddle..that would be more better

Comment: I dont have code for this..

Comment: here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/c4EXHa0C8jjPIRT6e6sN?p=preview

Comment: have you went through this http://mobileangularui.com/docs/module:mobile-angular-ui.gestures/module:swipe/ link